# Discord Bot | Ranking (Leaderboard?) System with discord.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I have a few questions to ask about a ranking (leaderboard...?) system in discord.js using MongoDB. I am following a [tutorial made by CodeLyon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8no3SktqagY) for the setup of MongoDB, but afterwards I went ahead and created my own XP system.

I know that I can sort the profile models, but I don't know how. Also, how would I give each profile model a rank? For example, if a user called Dummy was 5th on the list, how would I give him a rank of 5? **Please read the parts after the code please, as well.**

Here are the files that I think are important:

**profileSchema.js:** Creates profile model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    serverID: { type: String, require: true},
    coins: { type: Number, default: 1000},
    bank: { type: Number },
    username: {type: String, require: true },
    discriminator: { type: String, require: true },
    xp: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    xpShow: { type: Number },
    level: { type: Number, default: 1},
    xpReq: { type: Number}
})

const model = mongoose.model('ProfileModels', profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

**message.js:** Message event

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const profileModel = require("../../models/profileSchema");
//create cooldowns map
const cooldowns = new Map();

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    let profileData;
    try{
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if(!profileData){
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                userID: message.author.id,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                coins: 1000,
                bank: 0,
                username: message.author.username,
                discriminator: message.author.discriminator,
                xp: 1,
                xpShow: 1,
                level: 1,
                xpReq: 100,
            });
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    
    
    try{
        const levex = Math.floor(((Math.sqrt(2500 +  (200 * profileData.xp))) - 50) / 100) + 1;
        const reqXP = levex * 100;
        const roundXP = 50 * (levex * (levex - 1));
        const showXP = profileData.xp - roundXP;

        const response3 = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate({
            userID: message.author.id,
        },
        {
            level: levex,
            xpShow: showXP,
            xpReq: reqXP,
        });

    } catch(err){
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        console.log("   ERROR (Probably an invalid variable)");
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        console.log(err);
    }

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    const validPermissions = [
        "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
        "KICK_MEMBERS",
        "BAN_MEMBERS",
        "ADMINISTRATOR",
        "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
        "MANAGE_GUILD",
        "ADD_REACTIONS",
        "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
        "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
        "STREAM",
        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        "SEND_MESSAGES",
        "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
        "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
        "EMBED_LINKS",
        "ATTACH_FILES",
        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
        "MENTION_EVERYONE",
        "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
        "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
        "CONNECT",
        "SPEAK",
        "MUTE_MEMBERS",
        "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
        "MOVE_MEMBERS",
        "USE_VAD",
        "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
        "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
        "MANAGE_ROLES",
        "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
        "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
    ]
        
        
    try{
        if(command.permissions.length){
            let invalidPerms = []
            for(const perm of command.permissions){
                if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
                    return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
                }
                if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
                invalidPerms.push(perm);
                }
            }
                if (invalidPerms.length){
            return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
            }
        }
    } catch (err){
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        console.log("   ERROR (Probably an invalid command)");
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        console.log(err);
    }

// If cooldowns map doesn't have a command.name key then create one.
    try{
        if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
            cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return message.reply("my commands are limited. I can\'t find that command!");
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

//If time_stamps has a key with the author's id then check the expiration time to send a message to a user.
    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
    }

//If the author's id is not in time_stamps then add them with the current time.
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
//Delete the user's id once the cooldown is over.
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

    try{
        //execute command
        command.execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord, profileData);
    } catch (err){
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I want to create a 'rank' profile variable in the profileSchema and profileData, then I want to set the rank of the user to this profile variable.

If extra clarification is needed, please tell me in the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a "rank" property in `profileSchema` would be an inefficient approach. Because the rank will change depending on how others' XP change, therefore you'll have to update every document in the collection once **one** user gets their XP updated/increased. A better way of achieving the same result is by writing a function that will accept the user's ID as its first parameter, sort the entire collection (ascending), find the index of the user's document, and increment it by 1 (because indexes start at 0).

A function that does that task would look something like this:

```
            //A file on it's own, which will export the function to make it re-usable in other files.
            const mongoose = require("mongoose");
            //modify "@models" to locate profileSchema.js
            const profileModel = require("@models/profileSchema");

            /**
             * 
             * @param ID The Discord ID of the user you want to locate their Rank in the collection
             * @returns {Number} The rank of the user
             */
            module.exports = async (ID) => {
                //https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/
                const userDoc = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: ID }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                //We return -1 (false) if the user doesn't have a document
                if(!userDoc) return -1;
                //sortedCollection is an array.
                const sortedCollection = await profileModel.find().sort({ xp: -1 }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf
                //indexOf returns the index, we increment it by 1 to get the Rank of the user
                return sortedCollection.indexOf(userDoc) + 1;
            }
```

In the example above, I assumed you want to have the function in its own file to avoid an even longer `index.js`. The function is importable, meaning you can use it everywhere in your root directory, if you want to use it in `index.js`, simply define a variable that refers to that file:

```
     const getRank = require("location to the file");
```

Then you can use it in `index.js` by calling `getRank(message.author.id)`.

**NOTE**
The example provided does not respect large mongodb collections. The .find() method returns an array of *all* documents in that collection, which consumes a lot of RAM, which might cause a delay in the client's response. To get over that problem, you can use a secondary (local) database like Redis, this answer is getting very long so instead, I will leave [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgpVdJB2sKQ) youtube link which explains what Redis is and why it is efficient to use to retrieve data which normally takes a long time to obtain.